# How to cancel a rpm installation

Tags: rpm

We are developing an application in python, and we are using RPM to install it. But sometimes, an error can happen during installation, and I can detect it. The question is, is there any way to cancel an installation if something is wrong? I tried to execute a "rpm -e package_name" command, but it's imposible because the system doesn't allow to run two RPM in parallel, so RPM is waiting my code to finish, and my code is waiting to first RPM to launch its own "rpm -e"

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Preferred approach is to separate installation of the package itself and initialization of the package data/settings. Let RPM handle installation of package files. RPM itself will handle file conflicts and similar things. Just specify requirements (Requires:) properly.

Then you can require a initial setup by the administrator before the application can be used. This is quite common approach with databases and similar applications.

However from your comment in other answer I am guessing your application is doing one ugly thing and that is: **it is modifying files installed by RPM**. That is not acceptable. You should always separate:

- code and shared data (icons, etc)
- runtime files (temporary files, cache, user-generated data)

Code and shared data is read-only for the application. It can be touched only by installer (be it rpm or some other package manager). Runtime files (usually found in /var/lib or somewhere in $HOME) can be changed at will and application should handle updates between versions as best it can of course. Packages should be designed so that:

- rpm handles code and shared data installation/uninstallation
- application handles runtime files updates and cleanup

In other words: **rpm should not touch runtime files and application should not try to touch rpm-controlled files**.

For example databases require administrators to dump databases before update, then restore them after new database is installed (new database can have different internal format of storing data). This is the last approach when no automatic conversion can take place.

Comment: How does Esabe's comment on Ignacio's answer imply that his/her code is modifying files installed by RPM? It sounds like his/her code is using "high level" RPM commands to check for the existence of the package and install/upgrade as deemed necessary.

Comment: +1 for the comment about Requires. But I find that the distinction between runtime files and RPM-controlled files may not always be clear cut, as the application "state" may (unfortunately) sometimes interfere or interact with the upgrade process.

Comment: Indeed the state may not be clear cut, but it always boils down to: does the application modify the file? Then do not package it, but let it generate the file/upgrade previous on first use. Installation is a separate step. As for the modification, it was just a guess from how I know some non-packagers usually misuse RPM. I might be wrong, and indeed rereading everything it seems likely. Generally for @Esabe: Look at how databases handle updates in Linux distributions and learn from it. It likely applies to your use-case

Answer (score 0):

Do not attempt to abort installation of a rpm package. Either fail to start installing, or notify the user of the error when they attempt to run the software.

Comment: I can't do anything of that:
First, I don't know if I have to cancel install until something wrong happens, so I can't fail to start installing (I understand that what you say is to check if something will go wrong BEFORE start installing)
Second, I can't notify user because  there is no user, I mean, is everything done by code, so my application checks if there is a previous installation, if so updates it and if not installs it, and if there's a problem cancels the install/update

Comment: @Esabe: The RPM --test option can at least tell you if installing/upgrading an RPM package will cause conflicts. So you *could* use this to do a "dry run" installation (and look for errors) before attempting a "real" installation.

Comment: @Esabe: also, you *do* have a user: administrator. You can fail to start after failed upgrade when manual intervention is needed and put enough information into syslog so that administrator will see what is going on and what needs to be done.

Comment: @Peter: --test is most probably not applicable here. It just tests RPM dependencies and file conflicts, but doesn't run either the application or scriptlets. Plus it expects that administrator runs this, it's not something that a developer can affect